# mysql_fetch_array within while loop is working in localhost but not working in host server

Tags: php

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM phpfox_education_question where subject_id = 2 and ques_id =1');
var_dump($result);
//var_dump result is :- "resource(64) of type (mysql result)" in localhost and web host,but
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    var_dump($row); //**NOTHING DISPLAYED in web host server but in localhost**
}
```

Comment: Are DB tables at webserver ok? Data exists?

Comment: Are the connection details the same?

Comment: Are your mysql credentials the same? Are the tables on the web server the same?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore. [see the red box](http://www.php.net/mysql_connect): the extension is being deprecated, use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM phpfox_education_question WHERE subject_id = '2' AND ques_id = '1'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); // <--- added this
echo "Results: ".mysql_num_rows($result)."<br />"; // <--- added this to output result count
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    print_r($row); //**NOTHING DISPLAYED in web host server but in localhost**
}
```

This is used depreciated code btw

Comment: Query is running but the result is int(0). I am dam sure that there is some data for this query. I have run this query directly in phpmyadmin and found data.....Pls help...

Comment: I have ammended the code above. It may pay to try to Insert into the database, it maybe that your database user may not have read access maybe. Just an idea

Comment: My query can read the all data from the table but not specific with where clause .....

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
var_dump(mysql_num_rows($result));
```

To see if there are any rows to be fetched, if not, that's your answer.
BTW, in PDO this code looks like this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=default_db_name;host=127.0.0.1',$user,$pass);
//use prepared statmenets
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM your_db.phpfox_education_question WHERE subject_id = :subject_id AND ques_id = :ques_id');
//pass binds when executing the stmt
$stmt->execute(array(':subject_id' => 2, ':ques_id' => 1));
//number of rows found:
var_dump($stmt->rowCount());
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{//fetch rows as assoc array
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Note that this is a basic example, there's a lot more you can do with PDO

*Update:*
To get more debugging info, try this:

```
try
{
    $db = new PDO();//connect, pass correct data here
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);//cause PDO to throw PDOExceptions on error
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM your_db.phpfox_education_question WHERE subject_id = :subject_id AND ques_id = :ques_id');
    $stmt->execute(array(':subject_id' => 1, ':ques_id' => 2));
    var_dump($stmt->rowCount());
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        var_dump($row);
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    $db = null;
    return;
}
echo 'No problems with query<br/>';
$db = null;//disconnecto
```

Make sure no errors are being thrown, if there are, check the messages, find out what is going wrong and fix it. If you can't find a way to fix them, we're here to help, of course.

Comment: var_dump(mysql_num_rows($result)); is return int(0). But if, i run the query directly in database it is working and it also found the data. Why not in my application?

Comment: Hi, "SELECT * FROM phpfox_education_question" is working but where clause "where subject_id = 2 and ques_id =1" is not working...

Comment: No error showing ....column name is same but i don't understand that why it is not working.

Comment: @Mostaqmahmud: I updated my answer with an example of how you can use PDO to debug a query. you're still using `mysql_*` extension, though... please don't, it's quite likely that your code will be issuing _deprecated_ warnings in the not too distant future. [read the docs to find out more on PDO](http://be1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)